# diffrent display in chrome and firefox

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, firefox

I have this stylesheet that my number has to be vertically center in textbox and it is okay in firefox but in chrome it shows me different

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box
}
html{
    font-size: 13px;
}
body{
    direction: rtl;
}
html, body, div, span{
    margin: 0;
}
.textContainer{
    position: relative;
}
.textBox{
    padding: 0 0 0 45px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    direction: ltr;
}
.mobile-number{
    background: url(phone.png) no-repeat scroll 7px center;
    padding: 0 0 0 46px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 42px;
    width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="textContainer">
     <input type="text" class="textBox"/>
     <span class="mobile-number">09</span>
</div>
```

Comment: Apply the `top:0` position for the absolute element. It will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box
}
html{
    font-size: 13px;
}
body{
    direction: rtl;
}
html, body, div, span{
    margin: 0;
}
.textContainer{
    position: relative;
}
.textBox{
    padding: 0 0 0 45px;
    height: 40px;
    width: 100%;
    direction: ltr;
}
.mobile-number{
    background: url(phone.png) no-repeat scroll 7px center;
    padding: 0 0 0 46px;
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    line-height: 42px;
    width: 10px;
    top:0
}
```

```html
<div class="textContainer">
     <input type="text" class="textBox"/>
     <span class="mobile-number">09</span>
</div>
```

Here you Go

firefox as the ability to set `Top:0` by default after `position:absolute` while chrome doesn't do the same until the value is set to `top:0`

so just by adding `.mobile-number{top:0}` your issue will get fixed

Comment: could you explain what you have changed and why?

Comment: have added `.mobile-number{ top:0}`

Comment: Adding explanation to your answer will always help to the OP to understand the issue. otherwise he need to compare your code with his original code. That is not the proper way of giving answer.

Comment: firefox as the ability to set `Top:0` by default after `position:absolute` while chrome doesnt do the same until the value is set to `top:0`

Comment: kindly add these explanation in your answer.

Comment: is it okay now ?@SureshPonnukalai

Comment: yes. This is much better.Always do the same whenever you give answer for other questions.